# Class "Illuminate\Routing\Redirector" not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I'm encountering an issue in my Laravel project where the use of `Redirect::back()` or `back()` is resulting in the error "Class 'Illuminate\Routing\Redirector' not found." Even when I attempt to use `Redirect::to('/')`, the problem persists.

Here's a snippet of the code in question:

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    return Redirect::back()->withErrors([
        'error' => 'Invalid login credentials',
    ]);
}
```

I've checked my `UserController` and made sure to include the necessary `use` statements for `Auth` and `Redirect`. Despite this, the error persists. I'm unsure what might be causing this issue.

Here's a screenshot of the error for better context.

[image: screenshot of error]

Any insights into resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Redirect class you should be importing is:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
```

If you are indeed importing the correct class and are still receiving this error then you are likely running into an issues where the framework is somehow caching stale data, so I would try the following to resolve your problem:

1. **Clearing the View Cache**: `php artisan view:clear` or `sail artisan view:clear`.
2. **Restarting Laravel Octane**: Restart the octane server (such as
   `php artisan octane:reload` or `sail artisan octane:reload`)
3. **Clearing Vendor and Bootstrap Cache**: Delete both your `vendor` folder and the `bootstrap/cache` folder and then run `composer/install`.